# Reuse element groups (that are other svg images) in batik generated svg

Tags: java, svg, batik

When generating svg with batik some elements are put in defs and reused.
But in my case i have many element groups I could reuse that are actually other svg images drawn on screen eg:

```
    <g fill="url(#b3)" font-family="'Segoe UI'" stroke="url(#b3)" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" transform="translate(56,24) matrix(0.6667,0,0,0.6667,0,0)">
      <rect clip-path="url(#b4)" height="17" stroke="none" width="21" x="1.5" y="3.5"/>
    </g>
<...>
    <g fill="rgb(66,66,66)" font-family="'Segoe UI'" stroke="rgb(66,66,66)" stroke-linecap="butt" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" transform="matrix(0.6667,0,0,0.6667,56,24)">
      <line clip-path="url(#b4)" fill="none" x1="22.5" x2="1.5" y1="17.5" y2="17.5"/>
    </g>
```

I would like something like that defined in defs and then reused with:

```
 <use xlink:href="#cube" transform="translate(56,43) matrix(0.6667,0,0,0.6667,0,0)"/>
```

Note that original group mixes matrix and matrix+translate, in my experiments I can do same or merge both into matrix for whole group in .

Any way to do that with batik, or will I need to write my own xml parser+optimizer?

Tried reading and debugging through batik but could not find a way to reuse such groups.